# Using sed to replace unique text with URL

Tags: url, sed, replace, find

I'm trying to figure out a more elegant way to replace a unique piece of text in a file with a URL.

It seems that `sed` is interpreting the URL as part of its evaluation logic instead of just replacing the text from a bash variable.

My file looks something like:

```
$srcRemoveSoftwareURL = "softwareURL"
```

and I'm attempting to (case-sensitive) search/replace `softwareURL` with the actual URL.

I'm using a bash script to help with the manipulation and I'm setting up my variables like so:

```
STORAGE_ENDPOINT_URL="http://mywebsite.com"

sas_url="se=2021-07-20T18%3A42Z&sp=rl&spr=https&sv=2018-11-09&sr=s&sig=oI/T9oHqzfEtuTjAotLyLN3IXbkiADGTPQllkyJlvEA%3D"

softwareURL="$STORAGE_ENDPOINT_URL/1-remove-software.sh?$sas_url"

# the resulting URL is like this:
# http://mywebsite.com/1-remove-software.sh?se=2021-07-20T18%3A42Z&sp=rl&spr=https&sv=2018-11-09&sr=s&sig=oI/T9oHqzfEtuTjAotLyLN3IXbkiADGTPQllkyJlvEA%3D
```

I then use sed to replace the text:

```
sed "s|softwareURL|$softwareURL|" template_file.sh
```

I recognize that `bash` is taking preference for the `$softwareURL` variable and inserting it in, but then `sed` interprets the URL as part of some evaluation logic.

At the moment my resulting template file looks like so:

```
$srcRemoveSoftwareURL = "http://mywebsite.com/1-remove-software.sh?se=2021-07-20T18%3A42ZsoftwareURLsp=rlsoftwareURLspr=httpssoftwareURLsv=2018-11-09softwareURLsr=ssoftwareURLsig=oI/T9oHqzfEtuTjAotLyLN3IXbkiIIGTPQllkyJlvEA%3D
```

It seems that `sed` is also finding any ampersand `&` characters in the URL and replacing it with the literal `softwareURL`.

What I'm doing now is to pipe the result to `sed` again and replace `softwareURL` with `&` which seems a little inefficient.

Is there a better way to do this?

Any guidance is most welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the current result is that in `sed` the `&` refers to the pattern matched in the first part of the `sed/s` command (in this case `& == softwareURL`).

One idea would be to escape all `&'s` in the replacement string, eg:

```
sed "s|softwareURL|$softwareURL|"          template_file.sh      # old
sed "s|softwareURL|${softwareURL//&/\\&}|" template_file.sh      # new
```

With this new command generating:

```
$srcRemoveSoftwareURL = "http://mywebsite.com/1-remove-software.sh?se=2021-07-20T18%3A42Z&sp=rl&spr=https&sv=2018-11-09&sr=s&sig=oI/T9oHqzfEtuTjAotLyLN3IXbkiADGTPQllkyJlvEA%3D"
```

---

If you find yourself needing to make several replacements:

```
$ somevariable="abc & % $ 123 & % $ xyz"
$ somevariable="${somevariable//&/\\&}"     # escape literal '&'
$ somevariable="${somevariable//%/\\%}"     # escape literal '%'
$ somevariable="${somevariable//$/\\$}"     # escape literal '$'
$ echo $somevariable
abc \& \% \$ 123 \& \% \$ xyz
```

**NOTE:** I'm not saying you need to escape these particular characters for `sed` ... just pointing out how to go about making multiple replacements in a variable.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I really appreciate the extra help. This worked out well for me!